# Можно ли отображать отдельные теги из одного html-файла в другом?

Tags: php, html

Хочу создать информер, чтобы отображал заголовки новостей со станицы новостей и хочется сделать, чтобы отображало не все, что на станице, а только один конкретный тег заголовка.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю насколько это грамотно, зато очень легко
`page1.php`

```
$mode="only_news";
include('page2.php');
```

`page2.php`

```
global $mode;
if ($mode=='only_news') {
    ...
} else {
    ...
};
```

---

Если `page2.html` статичный, то можно примерно так

```
$text=file_get_contents('page2.html');
$news=preg_match_all("div class=news(.*?)\/div", $text, $result);
```

---

Если `page2.html` динамичный, то можно примерно так

```
$text=file_get_contents('http://mysite.com/page2.html');
$news=preg_match_all("div class=news(.*?)\/div", $text, $result);
```